# Are there any desktops (intel or amd) or pci-e cards that can support more than 16 USB devices per port?

Tags: linux, usb-device, amd, ttyusb, lsusb

I have a custom device from a manufacture that creates 32 ttyUSB devices. But this doesn't work with pc usb's controller because this generates error "not enough host controller resources for new device state". I believe this is an issue with Intel and it only able to support 16 usb devices per port. As I understand it AMD AM4 motherboards can support up to 128 usb endpoints does that mean, AMD systems can support 32 devices per USB port?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This may be a software limit (i.e. in the kernel's usb driver) rather than hardware limit, and may just require patching and compiling a custom kernel.  What does the device manufacturer say about it?  Does the device's spec sheet say "doesn't work on intel"?  (it seems very unlikely that they'd eliminate over half their market).   Also, do they make versions with 16 ttyUSBs?  It may be simpler to just get two of those.

Comment: Is this on an USB2 bus, or an USB3 bus?

Comment: @dirkt is on a USB3 hub controller on my Intel NUC.

Comment: @cas is this a limit confirmed by the intel nuc community personal (16 devices per port).

Comment: And the limit is specific for USB3 (for complicated reasons); try USB2 if the custom device supports it.

Comment: @dirkt device is USB2. I'm looking for a computer that lets me disable XHCI. What a pain -_-